# Is $\mathcal{F}=\{\{2,4,6\},\{3,4,5,6\}, \Omega, \emptyset\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Hello so I'm trying to understand when a set can be defined as a $\sigma$-algebra (I'm new to this :)). I stumbled upon this question:

Is $\mathcal{F}=\{\{2,4,6\},\{3,4,5,6\}, \Omega, \emptyset\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

**My thoughts**

So I think it's not a sigma algebra because, a part of the definition states:
$$\text{if }A \in \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A^{c}\in \mathcal{F} \text{ with $\mathcal{F}$ a sigma-algebra}$$

So if we take the complement of the subset {2,4,6} you get {1,3,5} which is not in $\mathcal{F}$

The reason why I asked this question is because I'm not sure that this it totally true and mathematical correct.

If someone knows the answer and could share it we me it would be very much appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct, it is not a $\sigma$-algebra for exactly the reason you state among others.

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra must contain $\emptyset$, must be closed under union, and must be closed under complementation.  From this, it follows that it must also contain $\Omega$, must be closed under intersection, and be closed under set differences as well.  There are other variations on which of the properties are included as a part of the explicit definition and which are results which can be proven, but they all end up in the same place.

Comment: Thank you so much @JMoravitz for taking the time answering my question, you can't be sure enough with math :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct. It is not a σ-algebra.